# How to get the property value inside a spring bean class in my class ?

Tags: java, spring, properties

The things I did are:

- Created a property file (data.properties).
- Created a Spring.xml (I use property placeholder)
- Created a bean class.
- I have a class where I have to use the url value.
- I have a web.xml which has context-param where i set the param value to the path of the Spring.xml file.
- My codes are given below:

> Propertyfile:url=sampleurl
>
> Spring.xml:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath*:data.properties*"/>

</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.tempuri.DataBeanClass">
    <property name="url" value="${url}"></property>
</bean>
```

> beanclass

```
public class DataBeanClass extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{
private String url;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

> entry in web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:Spring*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now my problem is I dont know what method of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer should I override and what should I do to  set the value of variable url such that I can call it from other classes using getproperty() method.

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I was told that my bean class should extend some class and I should override one of its method so that I can use the property values in some other class. I assume the class to be extended is PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. I am not 100% sure though.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Ask for a requirement, don't ask for what to do, especially when it isn't clear what the expectation is.

Comment: alright the requirement is that I should be able to use my url value in the bean class in any other classes.

Comment: Do you want the value of "url" property in your property file, to be injected by spring into DataBeanClass objects url ?

Comment: @Subin : yes subin. how do i do that ?

Comment: since your "url" value is already present in property file, I think you want to use that property in multiple bean classes.

Comment: The value will be injected in your DataBeanClass without extending PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer itself. The configuration which you've done already looks sufficient.

Comment: Can't I put those values into some property object in my bean class and use it in any class whenever I need it ?

Comment: @antony.ouseph.k its already in url property of your bean. You can use the getter method on that bean to get url anywhere

Comment: @Subin: I tried getting the value like that. Not able to.

Comment: Are you getting a null value or any exceptions?

Comment: Yes I am getting a null value

Comment: How are you creating the bean object? is it created from Spring ApplicationContext or are you creating it using 'new'

Comment: +1 for that question. I am using new. but when I use applicationContext I have to mention the Spring.xml which I already mentioned in my web.xml. this confuses me.

Comment: ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
   DataBeanClass oBeanClass = (DataBeanClass) context.getBean("dataSource"); ----- here I have to mention the Spring.xml which I already mentioned in my web.xml. I was wondering is there anyother way to use applicationcontext ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815339/role-purpose-of-contextloaderlistener-in-spring

Comment: read the above discussion to understand real purpose of contextLoaderListener

Comment: You can always use `context =  ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();` as well to load the same context created during the initilization of container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can annotate your bean property like this, then spring will auto inject the property from your property file.

```
@Value("${url}")
private String url;
```

You dont have to extend PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Defining your bean like this will auto populate url as well, but annotation seems to be easiest way

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.tempuri.DataBeanClass">
   <property name="url" value="${url}"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: If I were to extend PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer how should I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Please do the following process to get property file value in class.

1. Define the bean for property file in your spring.xml
   `<util:properties id="dataProperties" location="classpath:/data.properties"/>`
2. keep your data.properties under src/main/resources.
3. Use the following code to get value from property file for e.g to get value of url key in data.properties

`private @Value("#{dataProperties['url']})`
`String url;`

Answer (score 0):

Properties files can be made accessible to Spring via the following namespace element in Spring.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:data.properties" />
```

And then you can use like

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
String url=env.getProperty("url"));
```

Note:

using `<property-placeholder>` will not expose the properties to the Spring Environment – this means that retrieving the value like this will not work – it will return null

Comment: but what is the point if env.getProperty("url")) does not work?