# Autowiring a DAO into a Service

Tags: java, spring, service, dao, autowired

I'm using Spring and am trying to autowire (using annotations) a DAO into a Service, which is then wired into a controller. Having

```
@Autowired
Movie movieDao;
```

on its own doesn't work, as I think the `new` method gets called, so that DAO isn't managed by Spring. The following does work, but it will look messy if I have to copy and paste that context configuration into each method

```
    @Autowired
    MovieDao movieDao;

    @Override
    public List<Movie> findAll() {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load("classpath:app-context.xml");
        context.refresh();
        MovieDao movieDao = (MovieDao) context.getBean("movieDao", MovieDao.class);
        return movieDao.findAll();
    }
```

where this code is in my Service class. Is there a more elegant way to ensure that my DAO is initialised properly, rather than copying and pasting the first 4 lines of that method into each Service method?

[edit] The class that contains the code above is a class called MovieServiceImpl, and it essentially corresponds to the DataServicesImpl class in the architecture described on [this page](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html). (I'll add a summary/description of that architecture and what I'm trying to do soon). This is the code: http://pastebin.com/EiTC3bkj

Comment: Can you give us more context about this class that contains that `movieDao` field? Generally speaking, I recommend constructor injection over field injection, largely for this reason.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a bit in the post and will try and update it soon. Autowiring a constructor sounds like it might solve the problem - I'll give it a go, thanks again.

Comment: I think the main issue here is you are creating a new applicationContext every time this method is called. Spring cant inject a dependency when used like this. Is this a webapp? If so you should set the context using the ContextLoaderListener like [this](http://syntx.io/difference-between-loading-context-via-dispatcherservlet-and-contextloaderlistener/) . The reasons for the contextLoaderListener are described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815339/role-purpose-of-contextloaderlistener-in-spring)

Comment: Yes, it's a web app. Thanks for the advice and link.

Comment: why you load the spring context for each findAll() invocation? @Autowired injects already this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main problem is that you want to instantiate your service directly (with `new`) and not with Spring:

```
MovieService movieService = new MovieServiceImpl();
```

When you do this, your `MovieServiceImpl` instance is constructed but not initialised (the field `@Autowired MovieDao` is `null`).

If you want to instantiate properly your object with field injection, you need to use Spring. As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection) or in [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/), you can automatically detect all your annotated beans and initialize them in your context with the **component scanning**.

### Example

In your case, using annotiations *on* (`@Component`, `@Service`, etc) and *in* (`@Autowired`, `@Inject`, etc) your beans, your project could look like this:

#### Spring configuration `app-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Use component scanning to auto-discover your beans (by annotation) and initialize them -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.se325.a01" />

    <!-- No need to declare manually your beans, because beans are auto-discovered thanks to <context:component-scan/> -->

</beans>
```

#### Entry point of your application `App.java`

```
package com.se325.a01;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.se325.a01.model.Movie;
import com.se325.a01.service.MovieService;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Let's create the Spring context based on your app-context.xml
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"app-context.xml"});
        // Now your context is ready. All beans are initialised.
        // You can retrieve and use your MovieService
        MovieService movieService = context.getBean("movieService");

        Movie matrixMovie = new Movie("Matrix");
        movieService.create(matrixMovie);
    }
}
```

In fact, when you are using Spring, it is really important to understand how the context is initialized. In the example above, it can be sum up as:

1. Your entry point `App#main` is called.
2. The configuration `app-context.xml` is loaded by `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.
3. The package `com.se325.a01` is scanned thanks to the line `<context:component-scan base-package="com.se325.a01" />`. All annotated beans (`@Component`, `@Service`, etc) are contructed but not yet initialised.
4. When all the beans are constructed, Spring initialises them by injecting dependencies. In the example, the `@Autowired` annotations which mark the dependencies are also discovered thanks to the line `<context:component-scan ... \>`.
5. The context is ready with all beans :)

### Notes

All this answer explains how you can use component scanning and annotations to use Spring in a `main` entry point. However, if you are developing a server application, the entry point is the `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

As @chrylis said, field injection is error prone. **Prefer using constructor-based injection**.