# Error due to listener in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, web.xml

when I am removing listener part from web.xml my project is running fine. Please let me know why?

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

    <display-name>migration</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

This is a spring web application in eclipse.

Comment: You didn't mention context param `contextConfigLocation` & path to `/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Comment: when i am runing this i m getting 404.but after removing that part its working fine

Comment: @OO7 for simple MVC that is not required.i think..

Comment: @Raju What do u mean by *simple MVC* ?

Comment: Simple MVC means his all classes will be written in on file i.e dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: i m writing an application using Spring MVC.so do i need contextconfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContextLoaderListener` is optional. If all you're beans are in the (child) web context (DispatcherServlet) you can remove it.

How it works basically, Spring load a root WebApplicationContext via Spring’s ContextLoaderListener and a child WebApplicationContext via Spring’s DispatcherServlet. This results in a parent-child context hierarchy.

If you don't need anything in the root hierarchie then just keep the DispatcherServlet.

Further reading :

- [Role/Purpose of ContextLoaderListener in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11815339/1140748)
- [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9016122/1140748)
- and of course http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have two config xml files. Say,  `SerivesContext.xml`, `ContextDAO.xml`
If you have configured everything in one spring config file you don't need the 
ContextLoaderListener, just the dispatcher servlet is sufficient.

If you use different ones , you can configure it as ,

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml,WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Web Applications, there are two types of container, each of which is configured and initialized differently. One is the [Application Context](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) and the other is the [WebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html).

**Purpose of ContextLoaderListener :**

ContextLoaderListener is used to initialize `Application Context`. In this case, you will tell Spring to load all `*-.context.xml` files from the `classpath`. There is **only one application context per application**.

So you can configure this in `web.xml` as

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:*-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Purpose of contextConfigLocation :**

On the other hand, you have [WebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html). [WebApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) is the child context of the [Application Context](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html). **Each DispatcherServlet defined in a Spring web application will have an associated WebApplicationContext**. You can initialize the WebApplicationContext as

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**NOTE :** Here name of the XML must be like `<servlet name>-servlet.xml`. In our case name of servlet is `dispatcher` therefore, name of XML file is `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

I hope this clears you when to use what & why.