# Spring REST always return 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Ive setup a simple REST API using Spring 4 with Spring security

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mysabisabi-servlet.xml,
     classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,
      classpath*:META-INF/spring/mysabisabi-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mysabisabi-rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mysabisabi-rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**AccountController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class AccountController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> updateRegistrationToken(@RequestBody RegistrationToken token){
    GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();
    //some code here

    return new ResponseEntity<GenericResponse>(response, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

}
```

**mysabisabi-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.mysabisabi.mapper.JsonCustomMapper" />

<bean id="jackson2HttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <ref bean="jackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

**mysabisabi-security.xml**

```
 <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
<intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
<csrf disabled="true"/>
<anonymous enabled="false"/>
<http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
<!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
<custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
<access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
 </http>

  <http pattern="/api/*" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
<anonymous enabled="false"/>
<csrf disabled="true"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/api/*"  access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
<custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
<access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mysabisabi" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mysabisabi.properties" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


//dataSource configuration
```

**LOG File**

```
2016-07-16 16:24:45 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:537 - Mapped "{[/api/update],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.mysabisabi.dto.response.GenericResponse> com.mysabisabi.controller.AccountController.updateRegistrationToken(com.mysabisabi.dto.request.RegistrationToken)
```

When I tried to access `http://localhost:8080/mysabisabi/api/update` I got  `HTTPStatus 404 Not Found - The requested resource is not available`

I've tried both `/` and `/*` as url-pattern but still the same.

Can someone point out what did I miss?

Thanks.

Comment: In which format your sending request to controller(Json/xml/plain Text).?

Comment: where is your spring config xml file. Please share spring conf file.If you are  using class file for configuration . share classs file .

Comment: your configuration looks fine.Change below code in web.xml.<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mysabisabi-rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/mysabisabi-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>.   And try once.Also check application log in case for some exception/error.

Comment: yes.. that solve it. thanks. can you add it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your configuration looks fine.
Change below code in web.xml .

```
<servlet> <servlet-name>mysabisabi-rest</servlet-name> <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> <init-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/mysabisabi-servlet.xml</param-value> </init-param>    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>
```

Also check below Url.
[Order of loading contextConfigLocation in web.xml of Spring Servlet project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539610/order-of-loading-contextconfiglocation-in-web-xml-of-spring-servlet-project)

Answer (score 1):

What's your application container?

Tomcat, for example, will add the app name to the link, as in `http://localhost:8080/mysabisabi/api/update`, while Google App Engine wont, as in: `http://localhost:8080/api/update`