# How does a web application written in Spring using only a single parent context?

Tags: java, spring

In the spring Documentation,definition under `AppliccatonContext` They have states that an `ApplicationContext` provides mechanism to Inheritance from a parent context and they have further explain this as follow.

> Inheritance from a parent context. Definitions in a descendant context
>   will always take priority. This means, for example, that a single
>   parent context can be used by an entire web application, while each
>   servlet has its own child context that is independent of that of any
>   other servlet.

According to their explanation,I need to know that How does a web application written in Spring use a single parent context? What kind of design approch they have used? and What are the pros and cons of using only single parent context? Can any one explain me this further with a proper example please.

Comment: This is answered mostly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539610/order-of-loading-contextconfiglocation-in-web-xml-of-spring-servlet-project

Comment: Those answers are only explaining the usage of the AppliccatonContext and parent context.Still not engulf to fulfill my question. Specially pros and cons of using only single parent context.