# How to add Spring dependency injection to a sub-module of a project not using Spring before

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Noobish question here, but I'm struggling to make this work.

I've an old project with submodules which does not use Spring or anything, just final class and static Instance.

*--- Main*

*------ Server*

*------ Business*

*------ Webservices*

---

Server has a dependency with Business and Webservices.

Webservices has a dependency with Business

Server is the sub-module with the web.xml file.

---

I have to add a new service in Business sub-module and I want to start using Spring and dependency injection to do so, in order to start migrating the project to Spring.
(I'm not talking SpringBoot, just regular Spring).

---

In Business sub-module, I did:

- add `spring-core`, `spring-beans`, `spring-contet` dependencies as well as `javax.inject` .
  Using spring version 4.3.2
- create an interface IMyService and its implementation MyServiceImpl and added the @Service annotation on the impl.
- add a `spring-context.xml` file in src/main/resources declaring `context:annotation-config` and `context:component-scan base-package`

---

Then I created, in my submodule a "bridge" to try and use the Spring bean from my submodule in a non spring bean of another submodule, like described here : https://blog.jdriven.com/2015/03/using-spring-managed-bean-in-non-managed-object/

However the context never get injected.

I've tried adding in the web.xml of Server the `contextConfigLocation` but no dice either.

What Am I missing so that my Spring context get initialized in the Business module ?

Comment: Have you implemented a https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html to load the context? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815339/role-purpose-of-contextloaderlistener-in-spring has information on its purpose.

Comment: Thanks bit confused as to how to declae the ContextListener as I do not want to use Spring for the View, just for business services.
Do I still need to declare it on servlet level ?

Comment: The ContextListener isn't for the `view` it's for creating the ApplicationContext and tieing it to the life of the servlet.

Comment: I have the following in my web.xml in JBOSS  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
            classpath:context.xml
        </param-value>
 </context-param>
     
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

Comment: @DarrenForsythe so I'm to add spring-web dependency to be able to declare the `ContextLoaderListener`. Ok thought I could do without that.